# How to handle ETL / ELT for data with various "custom" fields?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, bigdata, etl

I'm working on building a data lake and data warehouse.  My desired approach is to capture data and first load it into the lake.  The data will come in various formats such as CSV, JSON (nested data), or other formats.

One issue that I'm struggling with architecturally is the existence of "custom" fields in some of the data we capture.  Depending on the customers that the data is coming from, there will be a various number of fields of different types.

Example:
custom_field_1 might be used as a shoe size field for one customer and as a description field for another.

I can easily capture these records and store them as JSON in S3.  What would I have to do to store it in Parquet format?  Would my only option be to create separate groups of parquet files for each customer?

I would also like to be able to load this data into Redshift.  Are there any features of Redshift that can help with this situation?  I've heard that Spectrum might be able to help, but again, the fact that the fields are not set makes this difficult.

Has anyone out there solved a similar problem and how did you do it?

Comment: looks like you might need to have data cleaning / wrangling process in your pipeline.